# Problems using FFTW library in Linux and Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, fftw

So I'm working with some older code I wrote some time ago. I was originally going to port it to Windows, had some success, but quickly ran into other problems and decided to move back to a *nix environment. The original code compiled and ran just fine in the first try.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and have chosen Eclipse as my IDE. When compiling and running the original code, everything is fine. Now I've installed the FFTW library ([fftw.org][1]) and can't seem to build anything that uses the library.

I installed the library using aptitude in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libfftw3-dev libfftw3-doc
```

The library definitely exists:

```
~$ g++ -lfftw3
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And I've added "fftw3" to my project's properties->C++ Linker->Libraries list in Eclipse.

The header file  is found just fine.

When I go to compile, every single data type that is defined in the library fails to be defined, so essentially the compiler has no idea what to do.

I'm a bit stumped...

Here's one of the errors (they're all identical):
Line:

```
fftw_real a[M][N];
```

Error:

```
error: ‘fftw_real’ was not declared in this scope
```

I'm not sure what else to try. Your help and expertise is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**SOLVED! Here's the solution**

For anyone else working with *OLD CODE* and low on sleep, searching on Google and StackOverflow for a solution to a similar problem, learn from my stupid mistake instead of making your own.

The key phrase here is *old code*. My code was written for FFTW 2, but I'm using version 3 of the library, which has a radically different interface. I had to update all my code that uses the library, then everything worked as normal.

Doh! How dumb. I hope someone out in Google land finds this useful some day.

Thank you, Dietmar Kühl, for helping me realize what was wrong. I appreciate you taking the time to install the library and poke around; that was very nice of you.

Comment: The first error (resulting from `g++ -lfftw3`) seems to indicate that you tried to link the library alone. This won't work. You'll need to provide a program yourself (I can't comment on what it takes to add a source because I'm not using Eclipse). The other error looks as if haven't include whatever file declares `fftw_real` (I can't tell where this is declared because I'm not using fftw3 either).

Comment: That first error was to demonstrate that the library is definitely seen by g++. The "was not declared in this scope" errors are coming from the fact that Eclipse is somehow failing to compile using the fftw3 library. If I make a quick hello-world program and compile in the terminal with "g++ helloworld.cpp -lfftw3" then it works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't show how `../Source/ipTool.cpp` looks like. Did you include `"rfftw.h"`? The library has nothing to do with it so far because you have compilation errors, not linking errors. The library only enters the picture when the linker needs to resolve unresolved symbols.

Comment: <fftw3.h> is included, which is the required header.
I see what you mean about the compilation errors. I didn't mean to submit this message when I did (hit enter early), so please give me a minute to try what you said.

Comment: I downloaded fftw-3.3 and I can't locate an type `fftw_real` in there. What I could locate in the ChangeLog, however, is this statement: "fftw_real is gone" (in a comment dating 2003-03-14).

Comment: Solved! I edited the solution into the original post.

Thank you, Dietmar Kühl, for helping me realize what was wrong. I appreciate you taking the time to install the library and poke around; that was very nice of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `find fftw-3.3 | xargs grep fftw_real` reveal that

> fftw-3.3/ChangeLog:  fftw_real is gone

This seems to be the root problem (well, just providing an answer to have this question closed as being answered, really).